# How do I stack tool icons vertically

Tags: interface

Sometimes my tool bar icons end up in two columns, but I prefer them to be in a single column. How to I make the tools icons stack vertically? (I know this is a minor issue, but it annoys me.) Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.10, Windows 11

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to grab the border and move to the left:

[image]